# Hibernate JPA Annotation for specific column mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, one-to-many

Refer to the URL http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html_single/, section 1.2.4

It defines a set in the hibernate configuration.

```
<set name="emailAddresses" table="PERSON_EMAIL_ADDR">
   <key column="PERSON_ID"/>
   <element type="string" column="EMAIL_ADDR"/>
</set>
```

How can this be converted to JPA annotations?

I am not getting it right, something like this?

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
     name="PERSON_EMAIL_ADDR"
    , joinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="person_id")
    })
private Set<String> emailAdresses;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `Set<String>` you need `@ElementCollection` instead of `@OneToMany` (which maps entities rather than values)

Comment: +1. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-ofvalues for an example